# Receive data from server in Json for Swift

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I use this codes for login the user to the server, I works well but I have the problem to get the token

here, I receive the login data with `String` (the last IF)

```
   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = body.percentEscaped().data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        } else {
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
            }
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("data: \(dataString)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way that I can convert it to Json? Or In totally, in login process, I better get the data as Json or String?

Thanks

Comment: Yes of course, there’s plenty of articles, tutorials etc on decoding json in swift.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Swift 4, Swift has its own JSON [Encoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder) and [Decoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder)

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) is Apple's reference page. Check this out and figure out what you need.

and here is very simple sample code from me.

```swift
// YourTokenModel.swift
struct YourTokenModel: Decodable {
    var token: String
}

// YourTokenController.swift
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = body.percentEscaped().data(using: .utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("There is a error while communication")
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        print("No data comes out. Returning...")
        return
    }

    do {
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourTokenModel.self, from: data)
        print(decodedData.token)
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT! //
    } catch let error {
        print("There is a error while decoding your JSON Model")
        print(error)
    }
}

task.resume()
```